# How to configure IIS 8.5 to work with Asp.Net UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-ajax, iis-8.5

I've created an Asp.Net Web forms project and using an UpdatePanel to prevent page postback. The update panel is working fine in local testing and also working fine in Windows Local IIS but when I deploy on Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS the page posts back and update panel don't work. I've also debug the HTML page and it shows the error

> Sys is Undefined

I'm not able to know if it is the problem from server side or inside the project. Below is the configuration on System.Web and System.webServer in web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers></httpHandlers>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Ajax" verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: To me, this looks more like missing Ajax/JS libraries than some kind of IIS issue.

Comment: Any idea what `Sys` is? There is nothing for us to go on.

Comment: @vishgarg have u added scriptmanager also ? while creating updatepaner

Comment: I've included the script manager as 
                        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: The Website URL is https://www.startappglobal.com/pricing/Preorder.aspx

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sys is: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('

Comment: Then it is a Javascript issue, right?

Comment: Yes, but the ScriptManager I've included is working in Windows Local IIS. I'm not able to find it in any references :(

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with references of the ScripManager. I added the references from packages that were downloaded and it then worked.